# How to create Visual Stuio 2015 Angular 2 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular

I want to setup for learning an angular 2 (alpha46) project with Visual Studio 2015. I've made the following steps:

- Installed typescript from http://www.typescriptlang.org
- Created a project in Visual Studio 205 with the template "HTML
  Application with Typeschript"
- In the project folder opened the command window and run: "npm install 
  tsd" and "tsd query angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite --action install"
- Selected "CommonJS" as module    system in the Typescript build
  properties pane
- Added TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators = true (in xml syntax)
  to the .csproj file

But the file angular2.d.ts contains only some comments.
What I'm missing? I've read that the provisioning of typings has changed since alpha40. But I don't knowe how to handle it. (I'm a newbie of npm).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some changes on how to reference the angular2 typings in alpha.46: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5248

try installing the angular2 npm package:

npm install angular2 --save. The typing's will be installed into node_modules/angular2

You can also try running:
npm install angular2@^2.0.0-alpha.44

and then copy the 4 files from node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings/angular2 into your typing s folder created by your tsd command.

This is the current version used in all angular.io docs at the moment anyway so should be a good version to get started on. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest